# Unable to run Java Maven Project Jar file

Tags: java

This is my first Java Maven Project. I'm running Project on NetBeans IDE. I am however unable to run the jar file from the target folder after I closed the IDE. I definitely know my pom.xml file is not missing some configs. I'd appreciate it if someone can tell me what I need to add, remove or modify. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.ZipTest</groupId>
<artifactId>ZipTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <copyright>Lati Jr</copyright>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Mavven package plugin -->
        <plugin>


            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.company.ZipTest.main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Not clear how you're running it.

Comment: You say you're "unable to run the jar file", can you explain what happens when you try to?

Comment: `java -jar ZipTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` should work if there's no external properties.

Comment: After I close Netbeans, I go to directory and click ZipTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar but application unable to run.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly configuring the main class. It is not the exec-maven-plugin you are looking for, it is the maven-jar-plugin that needs configuration.

Example taken from [here](http://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>
                    com.company.ZipTest.main
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maven exec is for executing something **during** the build.